# Background scrolling in IPhone6 with fancybox popup box

Tags: jquery, fancybox

When I open the fancy box in Iphone6 the background is scrolling here in my website. So that the user can not stay at the position when he opened the box.

We have tried in sevaral ways like adding over flow hidden and position fixed, then the scrolling is working but the background is going to top of the page.

Can someone helps me how can I resolve it...

Thanks
Sateesh